# coming back to previous search results

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse

I am curretly working on a project where is have to search references and go to them to fix some issues, and I often have to find references inside those references also.
What happends is that the old reference is deleted from the search window.
I was wondering if there is a way to open the new reference in a new sub tab inside the search tab in eclipse so I could go back to the exact place in the old reference list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is search history menu in the search window. [show previous searches](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcsearchview.htm) is the button you are looking for.